# ObjectiveC crashing when calling completion block

Tags: objective-c, closures

I'm getting a crash when a block is called after a network call. Here is the code:

```
- (void) signInUser:(NSString*) username
           password:(NSString*)password
            success: (void(^)())success
            failure:(void(^)(NSError *error))failure
{
    self.api.username = username;
    self.api.password = password;

    [self.api getAuthorityFeatureStatusCompletion:^(NSDictionary *dict) {

        //successfully auth, save the credentials
        [SSKeychain setPassword:password
                     forService:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]
                        account:username];


        NSString *accountCodesEnabled = [[dict valueForKey:@"AccountCodesEnabled"] stringValue];
        NSString *isVismaEnabled = [[[dict valueForKey:@"VocuherAccounting"] valueForKey:@"IsEnabled"] stringValue];


        if ([accountCodesEnabled isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:accountCodesEnabled forKey:@"AccountCodesEnabledStatus"];

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:isVismaEnabled forKey:@"GetStatusOfVismaEnabled"];

        } else {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"0" forKey:@"GetStatusOfVismaEnabled"];
        }

        //as we were able to sign in, get the other data we need for app to work



        success();           <============ crashes when calling this guy

    }
                                 andErrorHandling:^(NSError *error) {
        //we could not get the info for some reason, abandon
        api.username = nil;
        api.password = nil;
        failure(error);
    }];




}
```

I checked, my success block is not nil and the strange part is that if I comment out the code above the success() call, it works fine. So it suggests to me that the block is not getting retained properly maybe, but i'm unsure about how to go and fix it. 
I tried copying the block in each of the scope, but that did not fix it either.

Crash is: Thread 11: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x6b0b), 
no data in the console, 
stack trace

```
#0  0x00007fff50bad357 in objc_retain ()
#1  0x00007fff50bad65d in objc_storeStrong ()
#2  0x00000001083f600b in __29-[LoginViewController login:]_block_invoke at /Users/otusweb/Projects/MoreFlo/ISUPOS/Controllers/View Controller/LoginViewController.m:309
#3  0x000000010842b72e in __51-[UserManager signInUser:password:success:failure:]_block_invoke at /Users/otusweb/Projects/MoreFlo/ISUPOS/Managers/UserManager.m:78
#4  0x00000001085bb221 in -[APIMaster handleAPIResponseWithData:response:error:success:failure:] at /Users/otusweb/Projects/MoreFlo/ISUPOS/Models/WebClasses/APIMaster.m:697
#5  0x00000001085b5a21 in __66-[APIMaster getAuthorityFeatureStatusCompletion:andErrorHandling:]_block_invoke at /Users/otusweb/Projects/MoreFlo/ISUPOS/Models/WebClasses/APIMaster.m:88
```

And the code from where I call this method (which is called when tapping on a button):

```
[self.userManager signInUser:self.textFieldEmail.text
                        password:self.textFieldPassword.text
                         success:^(NSDictionary *dict) {
        //successfully auth,
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView: self.view animated:true];
        });
    }
```

Any clues?

Comment: Could you show the code of where you call that method?

Comment: @Larme just added it

Comment: No error param used? Also, not that the block is different for success ;) So I think that's why you have the error, it's not the same one.  In method definition: `success: (void(^)())success` vs in use: `success:^(NSDictionary *dict)`.

Comment: Exactly what Larme said, the type of the block you're passing to the method doesn't match the declared type.

Comment: Agreed, in the success block, ARC is likely trying to retain the dict argument, but nothing is passed in so it's retaining a garbage pointer.

Comment: There should be a compiler warning telling you that there is a missing argument.   @CarlLindberg is most likely absolutely correct in his assessment.

Comment: @Larme you are right the mismatch in signature seems to be the issue. if you add your comment as an answer I'll be happy to mark it as the right answer.